# como ejecutar un subproccess con un usuario NO root

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trabajando en *raspberry 4* con *raspbian*.

Por motivos que no vienen a cuento es preciso ejecutar un script [python](/questions/tagged/python) con `sudo`.

Dentro de este otro necesito ejecutar otro script tal como:

```
if "lo que sea":
   os.system('python3 script2.py')
```

Este `script2.py` solo funciona si no se ejecuta con `sudo`, puesto que abre el *chromium* y este no se puede ejecutar como *root*.

Lo que ocurre es que, aunque no pongo el `sudo` delante del comando, al ser un hijo se ejecuta como tal.

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: `sudo` sirve para ejecutar comandos como cualquier otro usuario, no sólo `root`. Prueba `sudo -u daniel python3 script2.py`

Comment: Funciona de maravilla muchísimas gracias.